# horizontal line align with the text and icon navbar bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

create a line horizontal centered with the text and the navbar

I'm trying to build my portfolio. The idea was create an icon navbar align to the left and align to right put < / Front-end Web Developer > with an horizontal line to the left of the text.
Something like in the image, I already have the nav icon but I can't implement the line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StW7z.png)

````
   <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <ul class="nav justify-content-left">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">
                                <i class="fas fa-home" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#about" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-user" style="color: #0d0d0d;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-th-large" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#contacts" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-comment-alt" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <h5 class="text-end"> < / Front-End Web Developer > </h5>
                </div>
            </div>   ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">
                        <i class="fas fa-home text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="fas fa-user" style="color: #0d0d0d;"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="fas fa-th-large text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#contacts" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment-alt text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <hr class="flex-grow-1 mx-3">
            <h5> < / Front-End Web Developer > </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
```

By the way you should avoid inline styles. It's best practice to use classes so you should replace `style="color: #000000;"` with bootstraps `text-white` class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [flex-grow-1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) utilities also, use `<hr>` element for [horizontal line](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/reboot/#horizontal-rules). Please try below code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <ul class="nav justify-content-left">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">
                                <i class="fas fa-home" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#about" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-user" style="color: #0d0d0d;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-th-large" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#contacts" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-comment-alt" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col flex-grow-1">
                  <hr class="border-2 opacity-8">
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <h5 class="mb-0"> < / Front-End Web Developer > </h5>
                </div>
            </div> 
    </div>
```